# Crop part of screen share WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, screensharing

I am developing a screen share web application where I should be able to crop area of screen to share with other users. I got this url (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/cropped-screen-sharing.html#21705984193804362) working but frames per second with this example are very low. Is there any solution to make it work well ?